# Dart chucked HTTP server response

Tags: flutter, dart, http, go, audio

I'm developing a simple Dart HTTP server which must return the values of a stream as HTTP response. I want to send the data of the streams in chunks, does someone know how to do this in Dart? I have created the application once before in Go, this is how the code looked like:

```
...
func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    flusher, ok := w.(http.Flusher)

    w.Header().Set("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff")
    w.Header().Set("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "audio/mpeg")

    for (...) {
        w.Write(b)
        flusher.Flush()
    }
    
    ...
}
...
```

This is what I have so far in Dart, but the flush function does not work as I expected:

```
final server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 8080);
    await for (var request in server) {
      final stream = await _audio.stream();
      final response = request.response;

      StreamSubscription? subscription;

      response.done.then((value) => subscription?.cancel());

      request.response
        ..headers.contentType = ContentType("audio", "mpeg")
        ..headers.add("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
        ..headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        ..headers.add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff")
        ..headers.add("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");

      subscription = stream?.listen((event) {
        response.write(event);
        response.flush(); // Here
      });
    }
```

The flush method throws an error when called, namely "Bad state: StreamSink is bound to a stream".

Comment: `response` is an `IOSink` so why don't you `response.addStream(stream);` instead of listening to the stream yourself. You can await the result to know when the stream has been processed. What were you intending by the `flush`?

Comment: @RichardHeap it's an audio live stream, so the request has a shorter live span than the stream. And values will be added to the stream during the request. Is it possible to use the `addStream()` function for this?

Comment: @RichardHeap I was trying with the `flush()` function to send the written bytes to the client in chunks.

Comment: `addStream` should work, but don't await the result or you'll wait forever. There's a chance that the server will try to buffer the whole stream before sending it, so explore the settings to try to find any options that prevent that.

Comment: For example, when using shelf, you set `shelf.io.buffer_output` to false in the context to prevent buffer. Not sure if there's an equivalent for `HttpServer`.

Comment: @RichardHeap can you provide an example using shelf?

Answer (score 0):

In `shelf` you can certainly stream without buffer, using a handler like this:

```
Future<Response> audioHandler(Request request) async {
  final stream = [await] getTheStream();

  return Response.ok(
    stream,
    headers: {
      'Cache-Control': 'no-store',
      'Content-Type': 'audio/whatever',
      // any other response headers
    },
    context: {
      'shelf.io.buffer_output': false,
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Then I get the following error: `FormatException (FormatException: Invalid hexadecimal byte 0x3A. (at offset 0))` when the second data package of the stream is published . (For every data type I tried, string, UInt8List, List<int>, ...)

Comment: Which "second data package"? How are you creating the stream?

Comment: `@override
  Future<Stream<Uint8List>?> stream() async {
    _stream ??= eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream().cast<Uint8List>();
    return _stream;
  }`

Comment: The stream comes from a Flutter EventChannel, on which multiple Uint8Lists instances are published

Comment: Feels like you need some debugging logging around what `receiveBroadcastStream` is producing. What runtime type? expected sizes? contains valid data, etc. What happens if you just listen to the broadcast stream (and don't try pushing it out yet) in a little test harness - does it look right?

Comment: Yes, it looks right. It's a filled Uint8Lists, and the filled in data looks correct.